# Add my custom chain types to Polkadot-js/apps

Tags: substrate-node-template, custom-types, types

I want to add my chain types to the `Polkadot-js/apps` in order to reflect the changes on frontend. I've tried generating types using [this](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/typegen) tutorial, but I've no idea how can I use them in `Polkadot-js/apps` for my custom chain. If anyone could point to a tutorial or an implementation to this, that'd be super helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Usage section of the Polkadot.js typegen tutorial](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/typegen/#usage) it first shows how to extract the types from your custom type definitions, for example see how the Edgeware team releases versions their types for the community [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@edgeware/node-types), then when they create an instance of the API they introduce the types registry to inject the types and override existing types as described [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.extend#extension) so the API understands the types from the metadata.

For example, if you built your custom chain using the substrate-node-template but you changed the implementation so the default Balance type of `u128` [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L64) became `u64` instead, then you would create the instance of your API with:

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';
const wsProvider = new WsProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:9944');
const api = await ApiPromise.create({
  provider: wsProvider,
  types: {
    Balance: 'u64'
  }
});
```

Alternatively you could create it using the syntax `const api = new ApiPromise({ provider: wsProvider, types: { ... } });` as mentioned [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/create#api-instance).

So if you were building your frontend based on the substrate-front-end-template then you would add those custom types [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template/blob/main/src/substrate-lib/SubstrateContext.js#L69) where they create the instance of the API.

As mentioned at https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9944#/settings/developer, if you are a development team with at least a test network that is available and listed at https://polkadot.js.org/apps, then you could consider modifying the [apps-config](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/tree/master/packages/apps-config) package and creating a Pull Request into the https://github.com/polkadot-js repository to add the types directly so they would be automatically configured when anyone tried to connect to it.

Or if you just wanted to interact with your custom Substrate node running on your local machine you could just go to:
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9944#/settings/developer, paste your additional types, and then press the Save button.

For example, below is an example of the custom types you might paste to be compatible with a recent release of the [Polkadot.js API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polkadot/api) where you could add the correct `AccountInfo` type for your chain, such as providing a value of  [`AccountInfoWithDualRefCount`](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/types-augment/src/registry/interfaces.ts#L85) if your custom chain uses the old-style double refcount (with 4 bytes missing) if the API defaulted to more recent [triple refcount](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/system/src/migrations/mod.rs).
In the example below we have also assumed that the custom chain uses a custom `Balance` type of `u64`, an `Address` type of `MultiAddress` as shown [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L305), and where a standalone chain is being used with [two session keys (i.e. Grandpa, Aura) in the chain specification](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L35) so custom `Keys` type of [`SessionKeys2`](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/types/src/interfaces/session/definitions.ts#L26) is used.
If you were to modify your custom chain to use four session keys instead (i.e. Grandpa, Babe, ImOnline, AuthorityDiscovery) then you would change the value to `SessionKeys4`.

```json
{
  AccountInfo: "AccountInfoWithDualRefCount",
  Keys: "SessionKeys2",
  Address: "MultiAddress",
  LookupSource: "MultiAddress",
  Balance: "u64",
  UserInfo: {
    "user_dna": "[u8; 16]"
    "user_name": "Text",
    "user_address": "AccountId",
    "user_storage_hash": "Hash",
    "user_dob": "Date",
    "user_reward": "Balance",
    "user_reward_at_block": "Moment"
  }
}
```

If you created your chain based on the substrate-node-template and in runtime/lib.rs you added the following types to configure the pallet-template.

```rust
impl pallet_template::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;

    // https://polkadot.js.org/api/types
    type UserDNA = [u8; 16];
    type UserIndex = u64;
    type UserName = Vec<u8>; // Text
    type UserAddress = AccountId;
    type UserExternalStorageHash = Hash;
    // https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/
    type UserDOB = i64;
    // https://substrate.recipes/currency.html#just-plain-currency
    type UserReward = Balance;
    type UserRewardAtBlock = u64;
}
```

Then in pallets/template/src/lib.rs, you could use [user-defined structs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.extend#user-defined-structs) and use them to set and retrieve data from storage, as shown [here](https://doc.deepernetwork.org/tutorials/v3/kitties/pt1/#scaffold-kitty-struct) in the Substrate kitties tutorial and elsewhere [here](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/node/blob/master/pallets/roaming/roaming-accounting-policies/src/lib.rs#L145).

```rust
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug))]
pub struct User(pub [u8; 16]);

#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug))]
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Default, Clone, PartialEq)]
// Generic type parameters
pub struct UserInfo<U, V, W, X, Y, Z> {
    pub user_name: U, // Text
    pub user_address: V, // AccountId
    pub user_storage_hash: W, // Hash
    pub user_dob: X, // i64
    pub user_reward: Y, // Balance
    pub user_reward_at_block: Z // u64
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. But, I'd want the types generated from `typegen` to be used in the `polkadot-js/apps/packages/apps-config/src/api/typesBundle.ts` instead of the `Developer` tab on explorer. Can you please explain how would I do that?

Comment: There are example PRs with "custom types" here: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pulls?q=is%3Apr+custom+types

Comment: At that link the best PR is by InterBTC https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/6779/files where they import custom types from NPM https://www.npmjs.com/package/@interlay/interbtc-types. PRs by Spartan, Subspace, KILT, and BitCountry are also good. You can't fetch from external json file like I did in this PR here https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/3084. Specify `minmax` for the metadata `OverrideVersionedType` (i.e. where min (v >= min) and max (v <= max)). Note that typesBundle.ts file is automatically generated by running `yarn run build:extra`

Comment: How did you get [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataHighway-DHX/node/master/custom_types.json) json file for your chain?

Comment: I wrote it manually